# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION Android 12

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-12

I am getting FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error while running on Android 12, app keeps crashing.

E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 332)
W/GmsClient: IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffe
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
at WE.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-495157437:288)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.p(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-495157437:53)
at BB.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-495157437:1849)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at Sp0.dispatchMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.apk-stable-495157437:223)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Comment: Did you figure it out? Interested in resolving this as well.

Answer (score 1):

First off, for some weird reasons you'll have to shut down your system and then power it back let's say after five minutes, then secondly you'll have to wait a bit after executing the task. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

We've ran into the same issue when running the app in emulator, which calls Google reCaptcha service. The solution for us is to go to Device Manager and 'Cold Boot Now' your virtual device.